# Issue exporting my MS Access Report data to Adobe Acrobat DC pdf

Tags: vba, ms-access

Could someone help me with my code i get an error "Object Required" on my jso.getfield line. I have tried researching the issue and no luck on a resolution i hoping someone could help me with this problem.
I have several other fields that i want to export to PDF. Here is just one of the fields in my Access DB that i want to place the value into the pdf field
Here is what i am using.

```
Private Sub cmd_PrinttoPDF_Click()
Dim RDate, TmpFileNm, FilePth, stDocName, NewFileNm, NewFilePth, NewFilPthNm As String
Dim Left_VOUCHER
Dim FileNm
Dim gApp As Acrobat.AcroApp
Dim avDoc
Dim pdDoc
Dim jso

DoCmd.Hourglass True
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Left_VOUCHER = Left(Me![VOUCHER], 2)
Select Case Left_VOUCHER
Case "C0"
     stDocName = "1131"
Case "CC"
     stDocName = "1131"
Case "JD"
     stDocName = "1131"
Case "J0"
     stDocName = "1131"
Case "MP"
     stDocName = "1131"
'Case Else
     'stDocName = "SF1098"
End Select

TmpFileNm = "TEMPLET_DD1131.pdf"
RDate = (Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd"))
FilePth = "X:\Access_DataBases\Exported_Reports\Checks\"
FileNm = FilePth & TmpFileNm

NewFileNm = stDocName & "_" & Me![VOUCHER] & "_" & RDate & ".pdf"
NewFilePth = "X:\Financial_Services\Checks\Vouchers\"
NewFilPthNm = NewFilePth & NewFileNm

Set gApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.app")

Set avDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
If avDoc.Open(FileNm, "") Then
    Set pdDoc = avDoc.GetPDDoc()
    Set jso = pdDoc.GetJSObject
    jso.getField("TEMPLET_DD1131[0].Page1[0].DISBURSING_OFFICE_COLLECT[0]").Value = "VOUCHER"

    pdDoc.Save PDSaveIncremental, NewFilPthNm
    pdDoc.Close
    End If
avDoc.Close (True)
Set gApp = Nothing
Set avDoc = Nothing
Set pdDoc = Nothing
Set jso = Nothing
DoCmd.Hourglass False
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated. Im still new to vba and truly new to trying to export data to pdf.
The error is Run-Time error '424': Object required.
When I debug it.. It highlights the line 
`jso.getField("TEMPLET_DD1131[0].Page1[0].DISBURSING_OFFICE_COLLECT[0]").Value = "VOUCHER"`

Updated:
I opened the watch window and this is what the results were displaying
`Watch :   : jso.getField("TEMPLET_DD1131[0].Page1[0].DISBURSING_OFFICE_COLLECT[0]").Value = "VOUCHER" : <Object required> : Variant/Empty : Form_VOUCHER.cmd_PrinttoPDF_Click`

Comment: Why are you using Adobe SDK to create a report? MS Access can export reports directly to PDF with [`DoCmd.OutputTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.outputto).

Comment: Is your Adobe PDF an Adobe fillable form?

Comment: It is an Adobe Fillable form. However im trying to keep the same layout as the DD form has. it also has Digital signature blocks on the form. And i am not sure how to add a digital signature box when i do a ```DoCmd.OutputTo```. If there is a better way i am open to suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the specific field value has that weird, long name with periods and square braces? Check edit mode of fillable form.